# Is it possible to run a make table query using a recordset as the source in MS Access (VBA)?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database and I am trying to deduplicate a table named `tblPrevious`.  I have created a recordset that selects only the distinct values from the table and I would like to use that recordset to overwrite the original table.  I am unable to use a normal make table query because I can't use `tblPrevious` as the destination and the source table.  So my plan is to create a recordset through vba, then delete the original table, then use the recordset to populate a new table with the same name as the original `tblPrevious`.  My other  option would be to create a new table named `tblPrevious2`, then delete `tblPrevious`, then rename `tblPrevious2` as `tblPrevious`.  That seems too messy to me.  Below is the vba that I attempted but I received a failure message that said "Runtim Error 3078, the Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query "rst".  Thank you in advance for your assistance!

```vb
Sub RemovePreviousDupes()


Dim rst As Recordset Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="DeDupetblPreviousExport", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

strSQL = "SELECT rst.* INTO DELETETABLE FROM rst;"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)


End Sub
```

Added SQL for `DeDupetblPreviousExport`.  Also note that in the above code I am just attempting to wrfite the recordset to a new table, if I were to get it to work I would then attempt to drop `tblPrevious` and the last line above would write to `tblPrevious` instead of `DELETETABLE`

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT tblPreviousExport.[Month Reported], tblPreviousExport.[Employee SSN],   
                tblPreviousExport.[Employee First Name], tblPreviousExport.[Employee Last Name], 
                tblPreviousExport.Pool, tblPreviousExport.OpCo, tblPreviousExport.Paygroup, 
                tblPreviousExport.[Effective Date], tblPreviousExport.[Medical Plan], 
                tblPreviousExport.[Coverage Level], tblPreviousExport.Type, 
                tblPreviousExport.[Tier Change Effective Date], tblPreviousExport.[Num Eligible Months], 
                tblPreviousExport.[Employee Ongoing Contribution], 
                tblPreviousExport.[Full Employer Contribution], 
                tblPreviousExport.[Prorated Employer Contribution],
                tblPreviousExport.[ER Contribution Already Received], 
                tblPreviousExport.[Total Contribution], tblPreviousExport.[Max Contribution]
FROM tblPreviousExport;
```

Comment: Why not delete dups in original table? Please show the query source of *DeDupetblPreviousExport*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  Not sure the best way to delete dups in the original table.  I am trying this as it seems to be the easiest way that I would know how to do it.  If you have a quicker/easier way then I would love to try it.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You can't run action queries with recordsets as a source (or really, any query).

Instead, use the source of the recordset as a source for your query.

If you want to write a recordset to a table, you can also consider creating the table through VBA, and then writing the records to the table using a loop.

Comment: So if I were to try that method I would need to create a new table, then delete the original table, then rename the new table with the name of the original table.  Do you know of a better/cleaner way to dedupe a table?  I'm struggling with this and it seems like it should be fairly simple to do without having to create extra tables etc.

Comment: If you have a primary key, you should just be able to dedupe in a single action query. If you don't, add a PK.

Comment: I didn't originally have a PK but I added one.  I know I've done it in the past but I can't remember how (been away from Access fore a while).  Do you know what the SQL would look like for that?

Comment: Generally: `DELETE * FROM Table t1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PK <> t2.PK AND t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 etc)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table maintains a unique primary key such as an autonumber, *id*, consider using pure SQL to de-dupe original table and avoid temp tables or recordsets. Specifically, run `DELETE` with `IN` clause to keep the minimum *id* corresponding to all matched columns.

```sql
DELETE FROM tblPreviousExport main
WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT sub.id
   FROM tblPreviousExport sub
   WHERE sub.id > main.id
     AND sub.[Month Reported] = main.[Month Reported]
     AND sub.[Employee SSN] = main.[Employee SSN]
     AND sub.[Employee First Name] = main.[Employee First Name]
     AND sub.[Employee Last Name] = main.[Employee Last Name]
     AND sub.Pool = main.Pool 
     AND sub.OpCo = main.OpCo 
     AND sub.Paygroup = main.Paygroup 
     AND sub.Pool = main.Pool
     AND sub.[Effective Date] = main.[Effective Date] 
     AND sub.[Medical Plan] = main.[Medical Plan] 
     AND sub.[Coverage Level] = main.[Coverage Level]
     AND sub.Type = main.Type 
     AND sub.[Tier Change Effective Date] = main.[Tier Change Effective Date]
     AND sub.[Num Eligible Months] = main.[Num Eligible Months]
     AND sub.[Employee Ongoing Contribution] = main.[Employee Ongoing Contribution]
     AND sub.[Full Employer Contribution] = main.[Full Employer Contribution]
     AND sub.[Prorated Employer Contribution] = main.[Prorated Employer Contribution]
     AND sub.[ER Contribution Already Received] = main.[ER Contribution Already Received]
     AND sub.[Total Contribution] = main.[Total Contribution]
     AND sub.[Max Contribution] = main.[Max Contribution])
```

Or with `EXISTS` clause:

```sql
DELETE FROM tblPreviousExport main
WHERE id EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM tblPreviousExport sub
   WHERE sub.id > main.id
     AND sub.[Month Reported] = main.[Month Reported]
     AND sub.[Employee SSN] = main.[Employee SSN]
     AND sub.[Employee First Name] = main.[Employee First Name]
     AND sub.[Employee Last Name] = main.[Employee Last Name]
     AND sub.Pool = main.Pool 
     AND sub.OpCo = main.OpCo 
     AND sub.Paygroup = main.Paygroup 
     AND sub.Pool = main.Pool
     AND sub.[Effective Date] = main.[Effective Date] 
     AND sub.[Medical Plan] = main.[Medical Plan] 
     AND sub.[Coverage Level] = main.[Coverage Level]
     AND sub.Type = main.Type 
     AND sub.[Tier Change Effective Date] = main.[Tier Change Effective Date]
     AND sub.[Num Eligible Months] = main.[Num Eligible Months]
     AND sub.[Employee Ongoing Contribution] = main.[Employee Ongoing Contribution]
     AND sub.[Full Employer Contribution] = main.[Full Employer Contribution]
     AND sub.[Prorated Employer Contribution] = main.[Prorated Employer Contribution]
     AND sub.[ER Contribution Already Received] = main.[ER Contribution Already Received]
     AND sub.[Total Contribution] = main.[Total Contribution]
     AND sub.[Max Contribution] = main.[Max Contribution])
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close to the solution when you stated:
My other option would be to create a new table named tblPrevious2, then delete tblPrevious, then rename tblPrevious2 as tblPrevious

Instead what will work easily is:
create a new table named tblPrevious2, then delete THE RECORDS of tblPrevious (NOT THE TABLE ITSELF) via a simple Delete Query, then APPEND tblPrevious2 records to tblPrevious

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses, I appreciate the willingness to help.  What I ended up doing was what I had originally thought would be a messy way but in the end was a lot easier.  I ran a make table query selecting only distinct records and named the new table tblPrevious2.  Then I just ran `DoCmd.Rename "tblPrevious", acTable, "tblPrevious2"` and it just replaced the old table with the new table.  It was a lot cleaner than I expected it to be and it works great.